# Performance testing for ios and android phonegap application

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, performance-testing

Can anyone suggest me is there any good tools,plugin's or API's for testing performance in an ios and android phonegap application. I have searched different sites for long but couldn't find anything for installable applications. All the test tools and API's are for web applications. Can anyone please help.

project uses HTML5,CSS3,jQuery,jQuery mobile,Backbone.js and Phonegap.

Answer (score 0):

phonegap is a webframe.

what they really need is to measure the performance of your javascript.

I advise not to use many libraries, even to avoid them as far as possible.

for animations, use the hardware acceleration provided css3.

also remember that a lot of mobile phone depends a s4 android or iphone 5 will have outstanding performance, however, economic or outdated versions of android or ios will be the real headache.

Comment: Vorge.. So can you please suggest something for measuring JS performance. something like navigation timing API.?

Comment: as I mentioned, this is a whole. when working with phonegap must take into consideration the javascript, css, html structure, etc.. 

if you gave me more details of the application you are creating, I might suggest more specific topics.